# How to backpropagate through embedding layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0, word2vec

I want to implement a Word2Vec using negative sampling with pure TensorFlow 2. The job is fairly simple, I have two embeddings `target_amb` and `context_amb`, I take some values out of them, dot product them, and by comparing to `y`(which is `(1, 0, 0)` here) I compute the loss.

The problem is in the backpropagation step. I don't know how to backpropagate through the vectors I've dot produced before. It is because the vectors (`middle` and `neighbor_choices`) are **Tensors** but they should be **tf.Vatriable**. I don't think It is good to convert them to tf.Variable, because then in learning I'll have thousands of tf.Variable and I'll go out of memory.

> What shall I do to backpropagate through the embedding layer?

The code is simple but when I run it I'll have an error due to `middle` and `neighbor_choices` being Tensors.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x, y = (('self', 'the'), ('self', 'violent'), ('self', 'any')), (1, 0, 0)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype='float32')

target_amb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(words_lst), embeding_size)
context_amb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(words_lst), embeding_size)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
with tf.GradientTape() as t:    
      middle = target_amb(word2index[x[0][0]])
      neighbor_choices = context_amb(np.asarray([[word2index[i[1]] for i in x]]))

      scores = tf.tensordot(neighbor_choices, middle, 1)
      prediction = tf.nn.sigmoid(scores)
      print(prediction)
      loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(tf.expand_dims(y, axis=0), prediction)

      g_embed, g_context = t.gradient(loss, [middle, neighbor_choices])

      optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([g_embed, g_context], [middle, neighbor_choices]))
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-1559a622fe62> in <module>()
     20       g_embed, g_context = t.gradient(loss, [middle, neighbor_choices])
     21 
---> 22       optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([g_embed, g_context], [middle, neighbor_choices]))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _var_key(var)
   1295   if hasattr(var, "_distributed_container"):
   1296     var = var._distributed_container
-> 1297   if var._in_graph_mode:
   1298     return var._shared_name
   1299   return var._unique_id

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @KorG My final code is here https://github.com/kiasar/Word2Vec_tensorflow